# File upload does not validate correctly in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, file-upload, controller

I've implemented an option for uploading pictures of employees. It is optional. However, if I try to upload a file that is not valid, it just seems to skip to the show-method, which first of all does not exist, and secondly is never called.

If I edit the form without a file, everything works fine, and the validation also works. If I upload a valid file, it works aswell.

I just don't get why this is happening

Controller:

```
    `public function update($id){

    // get the POST data
    $new = Input::all();
    // get the user
    $u = User::find($id);

    $picturevalid = true;

    if (Input::get('slett') === 'slett') {
        $del = $u->employeePicture;
        $del->forceDelete();
    }
    if(Input::hasFile('picture')) {
        if ($u->employeePicture) {
            $e = $u->employeePicture;
        }
        else { $e = new Employeepicture(); }
        $image = array(Input::file('picture'));
        $picturevalid= $e->validate($image);
    }
    $new['password'] = $u->password;

    // attempt validation
    if ($u->validate($new, $u->uid) && $picturevalid && (Input::get('groups') || $new['usertype'] == 2))
    {   
        if (Input::hasFile('picture')) {
            $imagein = Input::file('picture');
            $kid = Session::get('kid');
            $uid = $u->uid;

            // We should make an url-friendly version of the file
            $newname = $uid.'_'.$u->lastname.'_'.$u->firstname.'.'.             // newname:kindergarden+kidnr
                    $imagein->getClientOriginalExtension(); // punktum + filendelse

            $thumb_w = 250; // thumbnail size (area cropped in middle of image)
            $thumb_h = 300; // thumbnail size (area cropped in middle of image)
            $this->resize_then_crop($imagein,$newname,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,/*rgb*/"255","255","255");

            //url to be stored in the database
            $urlpath = '/Hovedprosjekt/app/storage/upload/'.$kid.'/images/thumbs/';
            $url = $urlpath.$newname;

            $e->uid = $uid;
            $e->url = $url;
            $e->updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            if(!$e->save())
            {
                //save unsuccessful
                return Redirect::to('employee/'.$id.'/edit')
                ->with('register_message', 'Endring feilet.');      
            }
        }
        $u->firstname = $new['firstname'];
        $u->lastname = $new['lastname'];
        $u->phone = $new['phone'];
        $u->address = $new['address'];
        $u->email = $new['email'];
        $u->zipcode = $new['zipcode'];
        $u->updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $usertype = Usertype::find($new['utid']);
        $u = $usertype->user()->save($u);
        //saves user to db
        if($u->save())
        {   
            if($new['utid'] == 2){
                //Styrer
                $kid = Session::get('kid');
                $kindergarden = Kindergarden::find($kid);

                $u->group()->sync(array($kindergarden->leaderGroup()->gid));
            }
            else {
                $groups = Input::get('groups');
                if(is_array($groups))
                {
                    $u->group()->sync($groups);
                }
            }
            return Redirect::to('employee')
            ->with('message', 'Ansatt endret!');
        }
        else
        {
            //save unsuccessful
            return Redirect::to('employee/' . $id . '/edit')
            ->with('register_message', 'Endring feilet.');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //validation unsuccessful
        //Get validadtion errors
        $errors = $u->errors();

        if(Input::hasFile('picture')) {
            $perrors = $e->errors();
            if(isset($perrors)){
                foreach($perrors->all() as $perror){
                    $errors->add($perror);
                }
            }
        }

        return Redirect::to('employee/'.$id.'/edit')
        ->withErrors($errors) // send back all errors to the login form
        ->withInput(Input::all()); // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
    }
}`
```

Models:
Employeepicture.php

```
    `private $rules = array(
    'picture'   => 'mimes:jpg,png,gif'
);
private $errors;

/**
 * Validation method
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function validate($data) {
    // make a new validator object
    $v = Validator::make($data, $this->rules);

    // check for failure
    if ($v->fails()) {  // set errors and return false
        $this->errors = $v->errors();
        return false;
    }
    // validation pass
    return true;
}`
```

User.php

```
    `private $rules = array(
        'firstname' => 'required|max:40',
        'lastname' => 'required|max:40',
        'email'    => 'required|email|unique:user', // make sure the email is an actual email
        'phone' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:7,20',
        'address' => 'required|min:3',
        'picture'  => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif|max:2046',
        'zipcode' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:1,4'
        //'password' => 'required|min:3',
        //'password_confirmation' => 'same:password'//required?
    );
/**
 * Valditation errors
 */
private $errors;

/**
 * Validation method
 * 
 * @return boolean
 */
public function validate($data, $update)
    {
        if (isset($update)) {
            $this->rules['email'] = 'required|email|unique:user,email,' . $update . ',uid';
        }
         // make a new validator object
        $v = Validator::make($data, $this->rules);

        // check for failure
        if ($v->fails())
        {
            // set errors and return false
            $this->errors = $v->errors();
            return false;
        }

        // validation pass
        return true;
}

/**
 * Validation errors
 */
public function errors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }`
```

The edit view:

```
    `@extends('employee.employeelayout')
    @section('title', 'Endre ansatt')
    @section('employeecontent')


<h3>Endre ansatt</h3>
@if (Session::has('register_message'))
    <div id="register_message"><p>{{ Session::get('register_message') }}</p></div>
@endif
<ul>
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ str_replace($eng, $nor, $error) }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
{{ Form::model($employee, array('route' => array('employee.update', $employee->uid), 'method' => 'PUT', 'files'=>true)) }}

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('firstname', 'Fornavn', array('class'=>'control-label')) }} 
    {{ Form::text('firstname', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Fornavn')) }}
</div>      
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('lastname', 'Etternavn', array('class'=>'control-label')) }} 
    {{ Form::text('lastname', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Etternavn')) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('email', 'E-post', array('class'=>'control-label')) }} 
    {{ Form::text('email', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'E-post')) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('phone', 'Telefonnummer', array('class'=>'control-label')) }} 
    {{ Form::text('phone', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Telefonnummer')) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('address', 'Adresse', array('class'=>'control-label')) }} 
    {{ Form::text('address', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Adresse')) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::text('zipcode', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Postnummer')) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('image', 'Bilde av ansatt(valgfritt): ') }}
    {{ Form::file('picture', null, array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Picture')) }}
    @if($employee->employeePicture)
        <h5>Nåværende bilde</h5>
        <img class="small-pic" src="{{$employee->employeePicture->url}}"/><br>
        {{ Form::checkbox('slett', 'slett'); }} Fjern
    @endif
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('utid', 'Brukertype', array('class'=>'control-label')) }} 
    {{ Form::select('utid', $usertypes, $employee->utid, array('class'=>'form-control','id'=>"select_usertype")) }}
</div>      
<div class="form-group" id="group">
    {{ Form::label('group', 'Avdeling', array('class'=>'control-label')) }} 
    @foreach($groups as $group)
        @if ($employee->group->contains($group->gid))
            <div class='checkbox'>{{ Form::checkbox('groups[]', $group->gid, true) }} {{ $group->name }}</div>
        @else
            <div class='checkbox'>{{ Form::checkbox('groups[]', $group->gid) }} {{ $group->name }}</div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
    {{ Form::submit('Endre', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary'))}}
</div>
{{ Form::close() }} 
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ URL::to('employee') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Tilbake</a>`
```

Comment: When you say "invalid file" - what is invalid about it? MIME? size?

Comment: Mime. It should only accept jpg, gif and png, and the update works fine if its one of them. If I try with a pdf, exe or zip it just shows a blank page and somehow ends up in the employee/number, and not the employee/number/edit-page